# How can I show one product from all categories? (iteration)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to show with each category products on a single product (for autocomplete).

Model:

```
ProductCategory has_many :products  
Product belongs_to :product_category
```

Controller:

```
ProductCategory.all.map do |pc|
  @products = pc.products.limit(1)
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @products.pluck(:name) }
end
```

of course, in `search.json` I have displayed only one product in a one category.

How can I show one product from all categories?

Comment: Move the `@products = ` on the line above.

Comment: how to make `pluck(:name)` to array?

Comment: Replace the `map` with `flat_map` and `pluck(:name)` with `map(&:name)`.

Comment: Note that this is n+1 queries, it's not a particularly good solution.

Comment: for a long time, but it works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's said, it's n+1 queries. So we can do something like that:

```
Product.select('DISTINCT product_category_id')
```

or

```
Product.joins(:product_categories).select("DISTINCT product_categories.*")
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't apply it to my question. I want to apply `.map` at request `Product.joins(:product_categories).select("DISTINCT product_categories.*")` and inside of the iterator to make a request `pc.products.limit(1)` ?

Comment: You will already get only one product from each category by this query. `joins(:product_categories)` joins the tables, so we have as many rows, as many products we have, but each row also has product category, but product categories are duplicated (because one category has many products). Calling `select("DISTINCT product_categories.*")` we make rows unique by all fields of `product_categories`, so product categories are not duplicated now, but as tables were joined, we have only one product with each category.